# ERD for a Lab Database

Tags: database, relational-database, entity

Question: In a database for a clinical reference lab a specimen, when taken, triggers a test order (for testing obviously) creation.If that test order produces a failure, the specimen is given a new test order and tested again until a non-failure result is obtained. And test order is created for exactly one specimen.

Would Test Order be a weak entity type since it is dependent on the specimen being taken, and without a specimen it wouldn't exist? Also, would this weak entity type be a self referencing one in the ERD since it generates another order if it is a failure? I am having trouble with this definition.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your diagram, `TestOrder` is a regular entity since it's identified by its own attributes (`TONo`). A weak entity would be identified by `SpecNo` and a value (e.g. an ordinal) that is unique within the context of each `SpecNo` at least.

Your design calls for total participation of `TestOrder` in its relationship with `Specimen`, i.e. a `TestOrder` can't exist without being related to `Specimen`. While weak entities necessarily participate totally in their identifying relationships, total participation don't imply weak entities.

It appears in your diagram that `Specimen` may participate totally in the relationship too, if a specimen can't exist without at least one `TestOrder`.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same) to a similar question on StackOverflow. It may be easier to understand these concepts using Chen's original notation which separates relationships from foreign key constraints.

Practically, I think your design is fine without using weak entities.

I also think there's no need for a self-relationship on `TestOrder`. They're already related by being associated with the same `Specimen`. All you need is the order of `TestOrder`s (e.g. via a weak entity's ordinal or via a `TOTestDate` attribute).